# How to extract department from page properties using Powershell's PnP and set it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, pnp-powershell, sitepages

I have the following page: `test.aspx`

[image]

But when I run Get-PnPClientSidePage, I do not see it as a value, even if I expand any of the items listed. Additionally, I don't see a description either.

[image]

Once I have the department value, I would like to set it to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-PnPClientSidePage` is now renamed to `Get-PnPPage` from PnP PowerShell `v0.3.15`. I will suggest you to update PnP PowerShell version, follow: [Updating PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html#updating-pnp-powershell)

Anyways, you can use below simpler PnP PowerShell script to get the department value from site pages library:

```
$page = Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/work/SitePages/PageProperties.aspx" -AsListItem
$page["Department"]
```

Where `Department` is internal name of your column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Site page properties**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

Then you can set the new value to department column using:

```
$page["Department"] = "Power Platform CoE"
$page.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Site page properties**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get existing value:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "SiteUrl" -Interactive
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage "Test.aspx"
$listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List "Site Pages" -Id $page.PageId
Write-Host $listItem["Department"]
```

You can use following code to set value:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "SiteUrl" -Interactive
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage "Test.aspx"
$listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List "Site Pages" -Id $page.PageId
$listItem["Department"] = "Department1"
$listItem.Update()
$listItem.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Make sure that in `$listItem["Department"]` you use correct internal name of of your field. Check [this](https://sharepointstuff.com/2022/02/09/find-internal-column-name/) to get your internal name of the field.